# Outlets to nil in subclasses of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm creating a custom subclass of UITableViewCell.  I have outlets declared as properties for UILabels, UIImageViews, etc.  Am I supposed to set these outlets to nil somewhere?  In subclasses of UIViewController, there's the viewDidUnload right, but is there something similar for UITableViewCells?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing - did you get an answer? Note that if you're using ARC as I amn, then timthetoolman's answer probably doesn't apply since dealloc is unnecessary, and by the time the system is actually deallocing the table cell, it must be deallocing the subviews too. I suspect that the answer is that you don't need to bother: that that UIKit takes care of views, but view controllers are not views so need to be cleaned up themselves

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell is a subclass UIView, so you'd handle clean-up the same way. But remember cells get reused as the table is scrolled, so you may need to setup the prepareForReuse method, depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you setup up your properties(retain, strong, assign, etc.), you will want to release the i-var and set to nil in the subclasses' dealloc() method.

That's about it.  If the tableCell is being reused by the tableView via reuse, then it will remain available to be reused when a cell of the same type is needed.  In which case if it is waiting around to be reused, it is still in memory and not deallocated.

Good luck.